# Can't create table on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to create a new table on phpmyadmin using the web interface to do so, the table is shown on the image bellow
[image: Table to be created]

But, when I try to run the query it gives me the following error:
[image: SQL Error generated]

So, I've tried to manually run the query, which is:

```
CREATE TABLE `gerenciamentod2`.`permissoes` 
(
    `cod_perm` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `perm_tipo` VARCHAR(20) CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `perm_dist1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `perm_dist2` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `perm_pags` VARCHAR(20) CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `perm_datainicio` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `perm_datatermino` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `perm_status` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `DELETED` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cod_perm`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```

But it also gives me an explainable (at least for me) error
[image: Error from Query]

What am I missing?

Comment: Try it without setting collation per-column. Do you know what collation is for?

Comment: use `CHARACTER SET latin1` instead of `CHARSET=latin1` .. from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html)

Comment: Is it not the coding of the chars on the db? I use latin1 general ci because my native language is Portuguese. Is your idea to set the collation after the creation of the table or to set only for the columns instead of the hole table?

Comment: Character Set worked for me, thank you. But that's odd, the phpmyadmin generated most of the query...

Comment: @PedroH.Forli This might be a bug in phpmyadmin. In that case, you may report it to [phpmyadmin official website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)